# Laravel. Не записываются данные в базу

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Делаю на проекте 3 типа содержимого: категории, статьи и страницы. Категории и статьи создал, между собой связал и все хорошо. Со страницами проблема. В общем. Создал контроллер Admin/PagesSontroller. 
Функция записи в базу при создании страницы:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $pages = DB::table('pages')->insert($request);

        return redirect()->route('admin.page.index');
    }
```

Рут:

```
Route::resource('/page', 'PagesController', ['as'=>'admin']);
```

Через миграции создал в базе колонки:

```
id  title   slug    published   created_by  modified_by     meta_title  meta_description    meta_keyword    created_at  updated_at
```

Вся суть. После заполненни формы вылетает ошибка https://prnt.sc/qz12j5

Ранее пробовал контроллер так:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $pages = DB::table('pages')->where($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('admin.page.index');
    }
```

Но так данные никуда не записывались.

Answer (score 1):

В ошибке все написано, аргумент `insert` должен быть массив, а вы передаете обьект.